# .NET: Retrieving SAML token programatically from ACS

Tags: .net, identity, acs, federated-identity, ws-federation

I'm trying to retrieve a SAML token programatically, for various reasons (curiosity, and testing sending them to a web service are the main ones), and am struggling to retrieve a token from Windows Azure ACS.

I've set up an Identity Provider using Thinktecture's IdentityServer, and am able to retrieve a SAML token from that using the below code:

```
public static string GetSamlTokenForUsername(string issuerUrl,
       string username, string password)
    {
        var trustChannelFactory =
            new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannelFactory(
                new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.Bindings.UserNameWSTrustBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential),
                new EndpointAddress(new Uri(issuerUrl)));

        trustChannelFactory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;
        trustChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = username;
        trustChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = password;

        try
        {
            var tokenString = RequestToken(trustChannelFactory);
            trustChannelFactory.Close();

            return tokenString;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            trustChannelFactory.Abort();
            throw;
        }
    }

    private static string RequestToken(Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannelFactory trustChannelFactory)
    {
        var rst =
            new RequestSecurityToken(Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Constants.WSTrust13Constants.RequestTypes.Issue,
               Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Constants.WSTrust13Constants.KeyTypes.Bearer);
        rst.AppliesTo = new EndpointAddress("https://localhost/");
        rst.TokenType = Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenTypes.Saml2TokenProfile11;

        var channel = (Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel)trustChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
        var token = channel.Issue(rst) as GenericXmlSecurityToken;
        var tokenString = token.TokenXml.OuterXml;

        return tokenString;
    }
```

In ACS however, I've set up my application as an RP, and have configured it to use two identity providers, one of which is my Thinktecture IP.

When I attempt to use the above code to retrieve a token from Azure ACS, it no longer works, and I have an exception thrown back at me.  I believe this is because my understanding of ACS's role is incorrect, and that ACS is the "federator" so I can't simply ask it for a token.  I now believe it is supposed to inform me of the available identity providers, and give me enough information to locate them and get a token, which I should return to ACS.

How exactly do I do this from code?  Is this WS-Federation instead of WS-Trust (I don't quite understand the terminologies yet)?  Assuming I can get a SAML token from my identity provider already, how do I get ACS to accept the token and give me a federated token?